# JavaScript Quiz Question, keep on clicking

Tags: javascript

This is a working JavaScript Practice Quiz made by a noob (me).

the problem?  as you can see the quiz, you can keep on clicking the answer button after you picked your answer. How can I avoid this?? I try using **onclick = null ** but I couldn't set it back to click state.

Thank you for your answers!!!!! 
[Here is the QUIZ](https://tools4you.neocities.org/Quiz.html)

```
<script>
    let answers = [{
        question: "01 What year is it",
        a: "1850",
        b: "1920",
        c: "*2020",
        d: "1995",
        correct: "c"
    }, {
        question: "02 What color is the Sun?",
        a: "*Yellow",
        b: "Red",
        c: "Green",
        d: "Purple",
        correct: "a"
    }, {
        question: "03 How do you say 'Hello' in French?",
        a: "I don't know",
        b: "Hi?",
        c: "Paris?",
        d: "*Bonjour",
        correct: "d"
    }, {
        question: "What was the color of Napoleon's white horse?",
        a: "*White",
        b: "Grey",
        c: "DarkBlue",
        d: "Rainbow",
        correct: "a"
    }];

    var slideIndex = 0;
    var scoring = 0;
    var q = document.getElementById("questionheader");
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var b = document.getElementById("b");
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var d = document.getElementById("d");


    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = slideIndex + n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        a.classList.remove("green");
        b.classList.remove("green");
        c.classList.remove("green");
        d.classList.remove("green");
        a.classList.remove("red");
        b.classList.remove("red");
        c.classList.remove("red");
        d.classList.remove("red");
        a.classList.remove("borderGreen");
        b.classList.remove("borderGreen");
        c.classList.remove("borderGreen");
        d.classList.remove("borderGreen");
        document.getElementById("Goodjob").classList.remove("show")


        if (n > 3) {
            slideIndex = 3
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = 0
        }

        q.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].question;
        a.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].a;
        b.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].b;
        c.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].c;
        d.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].d;

    }


    function checkAnswers(choice) {

        for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            let right = answers[i].correct

            if (choice !== right && slideIndex == i) {

                document.getElementById(choice).classList.add("red")
                document.getElementById(right).classList.add("borderGreen")

            } else if (choice === right && slideIndex == i) {
                document.getElementById(right).classList.add("green")
                document.getElementById("Goodjob").classList.add("show")

            }

        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag that gets toggled when an answer is clicked. If the flag is already set when an answer is clicked, don't do anything. When advancing to a new slide, reset the flag:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  slideAnswered = false;
  showSlides(slideIndex = slideIndex + n);
}

// ...

let slideAnswered = false;
function checkAnswers(choice) {
  if (slideAnswered) return;
  slideAnswered = true;
  // check answers for this slide...
```

```js
let answers = [{
  question: "01 What year is it",
  a: "1850",
  b: "1920",
  c: "*2020",
  d: "1995",
  correct: "c"
}, {
  question: "02 What color is the Sun?",
  a: "*Yellow",
  b: "Red",
  c: "Green",
  d: "Purple",
  correct: "a"
}, {
  question: "03 How do you say 'Hello' in French?",
  a: "I don't know",
  b: "Hi?",
  c: "Paris?",
  d: "*Bonjour",
  correct: "d"
}, {
  question: "What was the color of Napoleon's white horse?",
  a: "*White",
  b: "Grey",
  c: "DarkBlue",
  d: "Rainbow",
  correct: "a"
}];

var slideIndex = 0;
var scoring = 0;
var q = document.getElementById("questionheader");
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var d = document.getElementById("d");


showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  slideAnswered = false;
  showSlides(slideIndex = slideIndex + n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  a.classList.remove("green");
  b.classList.remove("green");
  c.classList.remove("green");
  d.classList.remove("green");
  a.classList.remove("red");
  b.classList.remove("red");
  c.classList.remove("red");
  d.classList.remove("red");
  a.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  b.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  c.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  d.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  document.getElementById("Goodjob").classList.remove("show")


  if (n > 3) {
    slideIndex = 3
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = 0
  }

  q.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].question;
  a.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].a;
  b.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].b;
  c.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].c;
  d.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].d;

}

let slideAnswered = false;
function checkAnswers(choice) {
  if (slideAnswered) return;
  slideAnswered = true;
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    let right = answers[i].correct

    if (choice !== right && slideIndex == i) {

      document.getElementById(choice).classList.add("red")
      document.getElementById(right).classList.add("borderGreen")

    } else if (choice === right && slideIndex == i) {
      document.getElementById(right).classList.add("green")
      document.getElementById("Goodjob").classList.add("show")

    }

  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.answers {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.borderGreen {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: rgb(248, 62, 62);
}

.Goodjob {
  display: none;
  width: 596px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgb(252, 199, 225);
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
  transition: ease;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      <p id="questionheader"> </p>
      <div id="a" class="answers" onclick="checkAnswers('a')"></div>
      <div id="b" class="answers" onclick="checkAnswers('b')"></div>
      <div id="c" class="answers" onclick="checkAnswers('c')"></div>
      <div id="d" class="answers" onclick="checkAnswers('d')"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="Goodjob" class="Goodjob">Good Job!</div>
  </div>

  <div>

    <button onclick="plusSlides(1)">next</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

On a different note, it would be best to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have way too many problems to be worth using in modern Javascript. Consider attaching the event listeners properly using Javascript instead:

```
for (const answer of document.querySelectorAll('.answers')) {
  answer.addEventListener('click', () => checkAnswers(answer.id));
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => plusSlides(1));
```

```js
let answers = [{
  question: "01 What year is it",
  a: "1850",
  b: "1920",
  c: "*2020",
  d: "1995",
  correct: "c"
}, {
  question: "02 What color is the Sun?",
  a: "*Yellow",
  b: "Red",
  c: "Green",
  d: "Purple",
  correct: "a"
}, {
  question: "03 How do you say 'Hello' in French?",
  a: "I don't know",
  b: "Hi?",
  c: "Paris?",
  d: "*Bonjour",
  correct: "d"
}, {
  question: "What was the color of Napoleon's white horse?",
  a: "*White",
  b: "Grey",
  c: "DarkBlue",
  d: "Rainbow",
  correct: "a"
}];

var slideIndex = 0;
var scoring = 0;
var q = document.getElementById("questionheader");
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var d = document.getElementById("d");


showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  slideAnswered = false;
  showSlides(slideIndex = slideIndex + n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  a.classList.remove("green");
  b.classList.remove("green");
  c.classList.remove("green");
  d.classList.remove("green");
  a.classList.remove("red");
  b.classList.remove("red");
  c.classList.remove("red");
  d.classList.remove("red");
  a.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  b.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  c.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  d.classList.remove("borderGreen");
  document.getElementById("Goodjob").classList.remove("show")


  if (n > 3) {
    slideIndex = 3
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = 0
  }

  q.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].question;
  a.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].a;
  b.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].b;
  c.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].c;
  d.innerHTML = answers[slideIndex].d;

}

let slideAnswered = false;
function checkAnswers(choice) {
  if (slideAnswered) return;
  slideAnswered = true;
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    let right = answers[i].correct

    if (choice !== right && slideIndex == i) {

      document.getElementById(choice).classList.add("red")
      document.getElementById(right).classList.add("borderGreen")

    } else if (choice === right && slideIndex == i) {
      document.getElementById(right).classList.add("green")
      document.getElementById("Goodjob").classList.add("show")

    }

  }
}


for (const answer of document.querySelectorAll('.answers')) {
  answer.addEventListener('click', () => checkAnswers(answer.id));
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => plusSlides(1));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: gray 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.answers {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.borderGreen {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: rgb(248, 62, 62);
}

.Goodjob {
  display: none;
  width: 596px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgb(252, 199, 225);
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
  transition: ease;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      <p id="questionheader"> </p>
      <div id="a" class="answers"></div>
      <div id="b" class="answers"></div>
      <div id="c" class="answers"></div>
      <div id="d" class="answers"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="Goodjob" class="Goodjob">Good Job!</div>
  </div>

  <div>

    <button>next</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm!!!  Thank you so much!!!! 
I fixed the inline handlers too, that's something I never seen before... but I'm reading about it just now!  Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)